# Make a custom array from HTML Table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I want to make a custom array from a html table ...
In Html table I have 6 Columns. I want to make array of first 5 columns 
I just want to get array of text , I dont want to include Button in that array, Table is of 6*6

```
var array = [];
var headers = [];

$('#tbl1 th').each(function(index, item) {

  headers[index] = $(item).html();
});
$('#tbl1 tr').has('td').each(function() {

  var arrayItem = {};
  $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {


    arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).text();
  });
  debugger;
  array.push(arrayItem);
});

alert(array);
$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
  dataSource: array
});
```

Comment: Hi can please add the html table structure

Comment: why do you need the second inline loop?

Comment: basicaly I want to make array from this table and then want to post that array as a DataSource to the DevExtreme GridView

Answer (score 0):

Use the [:lt](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector

```
var headers ={};

$('table th').each(function(index, item) {

  headers[index] = $(item).html();
});
var array = [];

$('table tbody tr:lt(5)').each(function(index, item) {
var temp = {};
  $(this).find('td:lt(5)').each(function(i, x) {
        var head = headers[i];
        temp[head] = $(x).text();           
  });
   array.push(temp);
});
console.log(array);
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/s6L0pok2/3/

Comment: `td:lt(5)` will give only 5 th column array? Isn't it?OP says `I want to make array of first 5 columns`

Comment: Its not working,... Nothing to display using your suggestions... madalin ivascu

Comment: @madalinivascu  your updated answer still not working

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [];
var headers = [];
$('table thead tr th:not(:last-child)').each(function() {
  headers.push($(this).html());
});
console.log(headers);

$('table tbody tr').each(function(index, item) {
  $('td:not(:last-child)', $(this)).each(function() {
     var arrayItem = {};
     arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(this).text();
      //array.push({headers[index]: $(item).text()});
      array.push(arrayItem);
  });
});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="5" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>HTML <span>HEADER TEXT 1</span></th>
      <th>HTML <span>HEADER TEXT 2</span></th>
      <th>HTML <span>HEADER TEXT 3</span></th>
      <th>HTML <span>HEADER TEXT 4</span></th>
      <th>HTML <span>HEADER TEXT 5</span></th>
      <th>HTML <span>HEADER TEXT 6</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 1</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 2</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 3</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 4</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 5</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 6</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 1</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 2</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 3</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 4</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 5</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 6</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 1</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 2</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 3</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 4</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 5</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 6</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 1</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 2</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 3</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 4</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 5</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 6</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 1</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 2</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 3</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 4</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 5</span></td>
      <td>HTML <span>TEXT 6</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what happens if the has more then 6 rows/columns ?

Comment: You can have as many rows as you want, script will work fine. You can give it a try.

Comment: Same goes for columns

Comment: so you're telling me if i have 20 rows/columns and i want the first 5 then this will work?

Comment: No, it only skip the last columns. So if you have 20 columns, you will get 19. If you want to have specific 5 columns I can edit answer then

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [];
var headers = [];

$('#tbl1 th').each(function(index) {

if(index<=4)

  headers[index] = $(this).html();
});

$('#tbl1 tr').each(function(index) {
 var arrayItem = {};
 $(this).find('td').each(function(index2){
  if(index<=4)
  {
  arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).text();
  }

 })
 
  array.push(arrayItem);
  
});

alert(array);

$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
  dataSource: array
});
```

Comment: what does this do?